# How to increase the speed of synchronisation?

Tags: bitcoin-core, synchronization, performance

What ways are there to increase the speed of synchronisation of the network, assuming the use of the main Bitcoin client?

Comment: Disk seek speed is the single most important factor. It takes you 0.5 ms to verify a transaction, but 5 ms to go to disk and save it. When buying harddrives, look at that. SSD's have short enough seek times that the exact seek time doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 10):

Pass `-dbcache=N` as a command line option. `N` is a number in megabytes, and setting it higher significantly improves verification speed. The default is 450, but up to 6000 or so you can notice improvements.

This is superior to using a RAM drive.

Answer (score 2):

Next to installing an SSD, and using `-dbcache=N` to allow Bitcoin Core to take more memory, each release of Bitcoin Core has sped up the synchronization.

The upcoming `Bitcoin Core 0.14.0` release will introduce the option `-assumevalid=<block>` which will cause Bitcoin Core to not check signatures up to the given block. This is by default enabled and set to a block shortly before the release. It has been reported that synchronization only took about [2/3 of the time with 0.14.0 than with 0.13.2](https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/5xomir/0140_is_a_beast_48_faster_initial_sync/).

So, if you're still on an older version because you're reindexing or hadn't turned on Bitcoin in ages, you'll probably see huge benefits by upgrading to a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to pre-calculate a subset of the data - this would be up to the author of the bitcoin client.

For example, the author of a particular client could say (to the program): "The first block is 286,427, it's hash is 0000000000000000f85c21f45015dcd2a89df40b03071234e1b3211aecaea1a4, and at that time, the COMPLETE list of balances is as follows: (include the full list here).

So long as the information is correct (and verified), and it is not on the wrong side of a fork, processing could continue from there. You would lose transactions before then.