# Blockchain download extremely slow at 200 blocks per hour

Tags: bitcoind, synchronization

I am running bitcoind and the blockchain download is very slow at 200 blocks per hour.

I am  at 225146 and at the current speed, it would take bitcoind a month to catch up.

Here is my output from bitcoind getinfo

```
{
"version" : 32400,
"balance" : 0.00000000,
"blocks" : 225305,
"connections" : 5,
"proxy" : "",
"generate" : false,
"genproclimit" : -1,
"difficulty" : 4367876.00084220,
"hashespersec" : 0,
"testnet" : false,
"keypoololdest" : 1378312057,
"paytxfee" : 0.00000000,
"errors" : ""
}
```

CPU usage is at 10 Percent and I am using 50% of memory.

Any ideas why the download is so slow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "version" : 32400

Oh my goodness. That is a very old version.

New versions dramatically improve chain synchronization times. Update from your current version of 0.3.24 to 0.8.5.

https://bitcoin.org

Comment: Thank you, that's the right answer. I had installed from Ubuntu LTS sources and apparently they are horribly outdated.

Answer (score 2):

The synchronization process will not only download the blockchain, but also verify each block. Besides the computational effort, this generates a lot of disk accesses, so if you have a slow HDD, an encrypted disk, or are doing a lot of other i/o at the same time that might be your bottleneck.

See also here: [How to increase the speed of synchronisation?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9277/how-to-increase-the-speed-of-synchronisation)

Edit: One might also want to check if *bitcoind* is up-to-date, the repositories of popular distributions can be lagging somewhat behind on fast developing projects.

Comment: But is the low number I am having seeing realistic, even for an encrypted hard drive?

Comment: I have no personal experience with the amount of slow down it would cause, but I've read about it so often that I think it must be significant. See for example [Stephen Gornick's answer on Why is downloading blocks taking longer and longer?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/4463/5406)

Comment: Apparently I was also running a very outdated version of bitcoind which I had installed from the ubuntu precise repo.