# How Do I use the prune option on bitcoin core?

Tags: wallet

How Do I use the prune option on bitcoin core ? as it is taking forever to sync

Comment: As Nick said, pruning doesn't speed up synchronization. I think you're actually looking for: [How to increase the speed of synchronisation?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/9277/5406).

Answer (score 5):

Like so:

```
prune=550
```

in your bitcoin.conf in your [data directory](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4006/where-is-the-data-folder-for-bitcoin-qt).

This will not make blockchain sync faster. It will make it take less space, though, which can be helpful.

(I have only 40 gigabytes of storage on my system, so this helps me a lot.)