# Can I interrupt the initial blockchain download without losing progress?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, installation, synchronization

I just installed Bitcoin Core through brew on my mac.
The blockchain is now downloading but it's slowing down, so I would like to restart it.
Can I abort the process and restart it and will it pick up from the last block?
Or will it start from scratch again?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I just open anoter terminal window and do:

```
bitcoin-cli stop
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining why this works: it instructs the Bitcoin software to flush the current state of its synchronization progress to disk, gives it time to finish that and only then cleanly shuts down. Also check out [How to increase the speed of synchronisation?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/22367/5406) for some ideas how to configure the node to sync faster.