# Bitcoin core synchronization too slow, only 16 hours of blockchain in 20 minutes

Tags: bitcoin-core, synchronization, mac, performance

I have Bitcoin Core stored on my external disk and currently I am on 39%. but the problem is that it is getting slow for some reason. The Bitcoin Core Qt app is constantly beachballing on my Macbook Air M1 for some reason. When I click on something the response will appear after 5 seconds or so, it's terrible.

Is this normal, or it will get worse?

Right now, I am on Dec 10, 16:23:29 2017 and it took 20 minutes to get there from Dec 10 00:20:02 2017.

Is this normal? Should I expect even bigger slowdown after 50 or 60% mark?

Any advice how to speed things up on my Macbook Air M1? I got to this 39% after running it for like 4 days - sometimes I turned it off for a couple of hours though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to increase the speed of synchronisation?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9277/how-to-increase-the-speed-of-synchronisation)

Comment: Try blocksdir if you have both SSD and HDD.

Answer (score 1):

Temporarily increase dbcache to the equivalant in MB of your RAM size and leave it overnight. Go to bitcoin.conf and add the following and save:
dbcache=8000

Comment: Any idea where is bitcoin.conf file located? I see only settings.json file here: https://i.imgur.com/0cKVXGj.png

Comment: Open Bitcoin Core and under Setting go to options then click button that says open configuration file then add your parameters and save.