Trouble with initial blockchain download for setting up full node
I am keen on setting up a full node to support the bitcoin network, however I am experiencing problems after initial setup when downloading the blockchain.
My PC specs are 3.2GHz CPU, 2x8GB DDR4 2133mhz RAM, 3.25TB of SSD + HDDs & Radeon R480 GPU
All of my hardware seems to be fine, but after running memtest86 multiple times with different combinations of RAM seated in all the different seats etc, ive realised that one of my 8GB sticks is failing. For whatever reason, my current setup seems unable to get through the full download without failing and requiring me to start over. I restarted the blockchani download process with just one of my sticks of RAM seated, and its been stuck after about 72 straight hours of downloading (however the process isnt autofailing and closing the client anymore, like it was when i tried with both sticks of RAM seated.
I am wondering if there is any less resource intensive way to download a current copy of the blockchain without doing it directly through the bitcoin core client. Or, if anyone has an idea of something else i could do to get this up and running id greatly appreciate it
Thanks!

Are you storing the blockchain on an external drive? R/W speeds of the disk can significantly impact the duration of the initial synchronization. Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/9277/5406

It's downloading to an internal drive, but it's a HDD not SSD. my OS and regular data is stored on a 1TB SSD that only has 400GB or so free so I can't use that, the other SSD is only 250GB so that's ruled out, so I was downloading to a 2TB HDD. Is it worth moving data over to free up my 1TB SSD? How much will it speed up the process? I've currently been at it for about a week with leaving my computer on 24/7 and it reckons it's going to take weeks and weeks. It's only something like 22% done

1-Address the Faulty RAM: Since one of your RAM sticks is failing, replacing it should be your first step. Stable RAM is crucial for such resource-intensive processes.
2-Use a Pruned Node: If you want to reduce the burden on your system, consider running Bitcoin Core as a pruned node. This reduces the blockchain data size, making the download and storage process lighter.
3-Alternative Sync Methods: You can also look into using a blockchain snapshot (UTXO Set) to bypass downloading the full blockchain initially. This can save you time and system resources.

Pruning means less data is stored but the download process still downloads and processes the entire blockchain, it is unlikely to reduce memory requirements much. Using a snapshot is insecure.
